# MVC 3 Image Upload

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a View that contains code that allows the user to upload images.  I pulled the code from a site that I can't seem to find. The code works great, but my users have asked to see a preview of the image before submitting the page.

My View has the following for my image and upload button.

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @if (Model.ImageData == null || Model.ImageData.Length == 0) { 
         @:None
     }
     else { 
         <img width="150" height="150" alt="Item Image" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ItemManagement")" />
     }
  <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
</div>
```

My BeginForm helper looks like this.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Add", "ItemManagement", FormMethod.Post, new{enctype="multipart/form-data"})) {
```

So, when my view is posted back, my Add Action in my contoller looks like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(ItemAddModel model, HttpPostedFileBase image) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return View(model);
        }

        if (image != null) {
            model.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
            model.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
            image.InputStream.Read(model.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
        }
        _itemService.AddItem(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Like I said everything here works great. But it's only once the form is submitted and my user opens the page again, can they see the image they've uploaded.  I'd like to add an Update button, that will get the image and load it into the image control without posting back to the server. I don't want to store the image in the database until the form is Submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code in my view. The important parts of this are the submit button's name being set to 'UploadImageButton'. This matches a property in my ViewModel which is used by my Action method in my controller. Also, the class="style-name cancel" keeps my Client side validation from firing.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @if (Model.ImageData == null || Model.ImageData.Length == 0) { 
        @:None
    }
    else { 
        <img id="itemImage" width="150" height="150" alt="@Model.ItemName" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ItemManagement", new { Model.ItemID })" />
    }
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false, includeFormTag: false, addText: "Add Image", uploadText: "Upload Image") <br />  
    <input type="submit" name="UploadImageButton" value="Upload Image" class="style-name cancel" />      
</div>
```

In my controller I have this code to handle HTTP Posts.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ItemEditModel model) {
    //Determine which button caused our postback
    if (!model.UploadImageButton.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
        //The user is uploading an image, so we don't need it check validation or update the database.
        //Clear our errors here so we don't show the user any validation issues. That will happen when the Save button is clicked.
        foreach (var key in modelState.Keys.ToList().Where(key => modelState.Keys.Contains(key))) {
            modelState[key].Errors.Clear();
        }
        var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest(); //Get the image from the request

        Session[ItemImageSessionKey] = image; //Save our image to the session 

        LoadAttributesIntoViewBagForEditView(model);

        return View("Edit", model); //Return our view and model with the users edits (if any)
    }
    //Normal code to handle Form submit (Save) functionality.
}
```

This now allows my users to Upload an image, which does a postback, but doesn't fire any validation an keeps their other edits in the state they were at the time of the upload.

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout the [following article](http://css-tricks.com/6522-ajax-image-uploading/). It uses the nice [valums ajax upload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Comment: I couldn't get the link to work. Shows as a black page. I was hoping for an way that I could upload the file to a temp folder and display from there. Perhaps as an AJAX call? MVC is relatively new to me, so I've got the basics down, but often have trouble figuring out more advanced stuff.  It seems anywhere you upload an image, you can preview what you've uploaded before submitting.

Comment: @Jeff Reddy, the link works fine for me. Are you behind some proxy or firewall?

Comment: I had to open in with IE, failed to render with Firefox. I'm attempting to use the Microsoft.Web.Helpers and the FileUpload.GetHtml. I'll see where I get with that.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use html5, you could look into the [html5 file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)